# error 401 azure ad b2c - google / linkedin

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I've trying to use Azure AD B2C as the identity provider for my application. I was able to setup using Microsoft Accounts and Email (let users use whatever they want).

However when trying to use Gmail or Linkedin, as soon as I select the icon in the login /register page, I'm getting a 401 error:

```
The OAuth client was not found.

Request Details
client_id=cc6323b1-dxxxxxxxxxx
redirect_uri=https://xxxxxx.b2clogin.com/xxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp
response_type=code
scope=email profile
state=StateProperties=eyJTSUQiOiJ4LW1zLWNwaW0tcmM6OGM2ZmI2MjAtZTI2ZC00ODdmLTliOGItYjg1MGNmYTMwNGM0IiwiVElEIjoiMTEwOGJiZTktNDY0NS00MzcwLTljYmMtZDNiZWUzNTM5NzA2In0
That’s all we know.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.... it's required to register the app on Linkedin and Google.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-google
https://accounts.google.com/SignUp

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-linkedin
https://www.linkedin.com/developers/